# Ancient sources on Ibrahimic traditions

Tags: prophet-ibrahim

Are there any very old sources from or about Hanif people, i.e. original Arab people referring to Abraham / Ibrahim independently from Jewish or Christian influence? I wonder whether Arab/Bedouin people were referring to Abraham independently from the tradition of the Torah.
By very old I mean from the ages of the Tanakh or before except the Torah that I know.

Comment: I wonder if this question is on-topic at all.

Comment: Just if anyone knows. Of course is it linked to Islam as it's told that the Prophet (p.b.u.h) was a Hanif.